# Flow Formula with a Picklist Field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, create-records

I am building a Flow that creates a new Opportunity if an Opportunity is Closed Won and meets a certain criteria based on a custom Picklist field called Coupon Type Used(Coupon_Type__c). The Picklist values for the Coupon_Type__c field are NULL,"No","25", or "50".

I am trying to create a flow formula that calculates the amount on the new Opportunity that needs to be created. If the Coupon_Type__c is 25 or 50, the amount for the new Opportunity record needs to be (Amount/(1-VALUE(Coupon_Type__c)*0.01))

I thought by putting in the VALUE function, it would convert the text in the Coupon_Type__c to a number. However I am getting an issue that is preventing me from saving the flow.

Is there anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklist field values can only be referenced in formula functions:

- `ISPICKVAL`
- `TEXT`
- `CASE`

You have none of these as you've jumped a step to convert a text value to a number using `VALUE(..)`

You will need `VALUE(TEXT({!$Record.Coupon_type__c}))` as your inner expression

Also, if null is legit, you'll need logic to deal with that as `1 - NULL` will cause problems

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this the inner expression was exactly what I needed. My formula seems to be working great thanks to your help. I have a validation rule in place where our sales reps cannot save the Opportunity as Closed Won if the picklist value is NULL. The flow will not trigger is the value is "No". I showed it to my boss and he approves. Thank you so much!